# Accessing a core's default handler through SolrJ using setQueryType

Tags: solr, solrj

I have several Solr cores on the instance, each with a `StandardRequestHandler` and some custom request handlers configured, e.g.:

```xml
<requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
  <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
</requestDispatcher>
...
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true" />
...
<requestHandler name="/custom" class="com.example.our.package.CustomHandler" />
...
```

I'd like to be able to access both of them through SolrJ, however, I'm able to do this via only via setting the `baseUrl` property of the `HttpSolrServer` object. This is however not desirable, since **the `HttpSolrServer` instance is shared between several threads, so race conditions would occur**. Another reason is that the team's consensus lies in **`HttpSolrServer` being `Singleton`-scoped for simplicity's sake**.

What I tried is something like this:

```java
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://URL_OF_SOLR:PORT/solr/");
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQueryType("/core/custom");
```

This works for the custom handlers, however it fails with code 400 when calling `/select`, at least for the URLs I tried (`/core`, `/core/select`, `/core/`,`/core/standard`), etc.

So my question is: **how should I define this query to correctly reference the core's default request handler, using only `queryType` or some other `SolrParams` value?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an use the `qt` parameter in Solr to specify a specific request handler, even the default `/select` handler. See [CoreQueryParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreQueryParameters#qt) for details on how this works. SolrJ supports this through the use of the `setRequestHandler` method on the `SolrQuery` class.

Some examples, assuming that your Solr instance is at `http://localhost:8983/solr` and you have two cores named `core0` and `core1`.

- `http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*:*` this uses `/select` by default
- `http://localhost:8983/sole/core1/select?q=*:*&qt=terms` this uses the terms requestHandler

Finally the core name should not be included in the `qt` parameter b/c that parameter is designed to support selecting a named requestHandler within a core. The Url for the Solr instance should have the core name within it as each core is its own Solr instance and therefore should be treated as such, IMO. From the SolrCore wiki page:

> Multiple cores let you have a single Solr instance with separate configurations and indexes, with their own config and schema for very different applications, but still have the convenience of unified administration.

So define multiple HttpSolrServer instances.

```
 new HttpSolrServer(http://localhost:8983/solr/core0)
 new HttpSolrServer(http://localhost:8983/solr/core1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already doing this - `setQueryType()` and `setRequestHandler()` both set the `qt` param. My problem is that I'm unable to provide the correct string to connect to the core's `select` handler. Could you include the appropriate string to set, for the examples given in the question?

Comment: If you just want to call the standard select, then do not set the `qt` parameter at all and it will use the one defined with `default="true"` in your configuration. BTW, I noticed that `setQueryType()` has been deprecated in favor of `setRequestHandler()` as of Solr 4.x. Additionally, since it is defined as `name="standard"`, you would need to call it as that, eg. `query.setRequestHandler("standard")` if you wanted to provide a `qt` always. Or if you want to use `/select' then you will need to change the name in your configuration from standard to /select.

Comment: If I do not set `qt` at all, how can I differentiate between the cores? Note the examples I've given.

Comment: See my edited comment above... You should not be using `qt` to set the core name. You should have a separate HttpSolrServer instance for each core that you want to access. `new HttpSolrServer(http://URL_OF_SOLR:PORT/solr/core0)` and `new HttpSolrServer(http://URL_OF_SOLR:PORT/solr/core1)`.  However, if you must use the `qt` parameter, then these might work - `/core0/standard` and `/core1/standard`.

Comment: Changing the name of the handler to "/select" indeed fixed the problem. Could you edit your answer correspondingly? Also, could you elaborate as to **why** `qt` shouldn't include the core's name?